# MailChimp API DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp::call() call to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to validate apikey but I am stuck on this issue if a user enters a apikey it should be validated from MailChimp account and should show a message of in-valid key if api key is not matched with MailChimp.

My Code:

```
public function authenticateApiKey(Request $request)
{
    $fieldsValidation = [
        'api_key' => 'required|unique:apikey,api_key',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $fieldsValidation);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $resultArray = [
            'status' => 0,
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            'dataArray' => []
        ];
    } else {
        $api = new APIKEY($request->all());
        $mc = new MailChimp($api);
        $mailchimp_ping = ($mc->call('helper/ping'));
        if(!$mailchimp_ping){
        }
        $request->user()->apikey()->save($api);
        $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Mailchimp Api key added into system successfully!', 'dataArray' => $api];
    }
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
}
```

When I hit this call it said `call to aundefined` method is there any other in which I can validate apikey.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
               namespace App\Http\Controllers;

                    use App\APIKEY;
                 use DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
                use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
                  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
                use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
                  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
                 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
              use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
            use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


          class ApiController extends Controller
         {

           public function authenticateApiKey(Request $request)
          {
              $fieldsValidation = [

        'api_key' => 'required|unique:apikey,api_key',

    ];
       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $fieldsValidation);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $resultArray = [
            'status' => 0,
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            'dataArray' => []
        ];

    } else {

        $api = new APIKEY($request->all());
        $mc = new MailChimp($api);
        $mailchimp_ping = $mc->get('/ping');
        if ($mailchimp_ping["status"] == 401) {
            return redirect()->back()->with("errorMessage","api key is invalid")->withInput(Input::all());
        }


        ///do here if api key is valid

        $request->user()->apikey()->save($api);
        $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Mailchimp Api key added into system successfully!', 'dataArray' => $api];
        //   }
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a `request`. If the request works, the key is `valid`. Follow [this](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/ping/#read-get_ping) link to make a `ping` request. It's a health check endpoint for `MailChimp API 3.0`.

```
$mailchimp_ping = $mc->get('/ping');

dd($mailchimp_ping);
```

Here is your requested full controller that works fine-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\APIKEY;
use DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class ApiController extends Controller
{

public function authenticateApiKey(Request $request)
{
    $fieldsValidation = [

        'api_key' => 'required|unique:apikey,api_key',

    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $fieldsValidation);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $resultArray = [
            'status' => 0,
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            'dataArray' => []
        ];

    } else {
        $mc = new MailChimp($request->input('api_key'));
        $mailchimp_ping = $mc->get('/ping');
        if ($mailchimp_ping["status"] != 401) {
             $api = new APIKEY($request->all());
             $request->user()->apikey()->save($api);
             $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Mailchimp Api key added into system successfully!', 'dataArray' => $api];
             return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
        }

          $errorResponse = [
                 'message' => 'Not valid api key!',
                 'code' => '401'
               ];
        return $this->apiResponse('error', '401', $errorResponse);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: can u please provide me a little demo how to make a request i am new to mailchimp and i am stuck in this issue any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: show us how you are making your request to mailchip, something that is working

Comment: $mailchimp = new \Mailchimp($api);

            $mailchimp_ping = ($mailchimp->call('helper/ping'));

            if(!$mailchimp_ping){
                //key did not work
                //do stuff

Comment: Nothing is working here u can see the code above from which i am making request

Comment: $api = new APIKEY($request->all());
           


            $request->user()->apikey()->save($api);
            $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Mailchimp Api key added into system successfully!', 'dataArray' => $api];

Comment: where you are making a request to mailchip?? could you please add that code, code that works for valid api key

Comment: here is the code i am just adding api key with logged in user now i want to make a request that will verify my apikey from mailchimp if its valid it show my the error if not valid it says invalid key or something

Comment: you don't have any code to make request to mailchip server??

Comment: Please see my code above at top which i have shared thats my code  $mc = new MailChimp($api);
        $mailchimp_ping = ($mc->call('helper/ping'));
        if(!$mailchimp_ping){
        } in which i am making request

Comment: this function won't work, ok, i will update my answer later

Comment: i dont know how to make a request to mailchimp server to validate api key please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: which function will work to make this happen. i will really appreciate your help if u provide me right now

Comment: $mailchimp = new \Mailchimp\Mailchimp( $api);

            $mailchimp_ping = ($mailchimp->request('helper/ping'));

            if(!$mailchimp_ping){
                //key did not work
                //do stuff
            }

Comment: here is my upto date code for making the request from mailchimp server

Comment: Mailchimp\MailchimpFacade::get()

Comment: this is what, is it a error>> whats the error, show full error please

Comment: Call to undefined method Mailchimp\MailchimpFacade::get()

Comment: please provide your full controller code with namespace

Comment: @syed1234 see my updated code, you were using wrong mailchip class, before start you should have read the documentation of this package. If you want to read, see this link https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api

Comment: Thanks for your help but its adding any key for example my valid key is 1234 and if i enter 23 its adding it. it should not add it its still not validating :(

Comment: that's your coding logic, solve your logic with pen and paper first by yourself, then look for code. One thing you can do now is to direct inside if block with a error message that api key is in valid

Comment: @syed1234 i have updated my answer, now it won't save with invalid key

Comment: yea its still not validating i am very confused its allowing any random string not validating sorry to say :(

Comment: post your latest controller and explain what do you want exactly

Comment: i paste my controller again what i want is my apikey on mailchimp is lets suppose 123456789 and user is entering this against his user_id if he enter key other than this like 1234567hjhjjh it should not enter this key the apikey should validate he enter exactly what is on mailchimp

Comment: its like email when we enter on any form the email should be valid otherwise if we enter wrong email it should display the message that invalid email .. same as mailchimp api key if he enter valid api which is store on mailchimp it should add successfully otherwise we cant allow to add any other string

Comment: see now and you should have tell us this is an api request. make a quick try please

Comment: sorry for not mentioning

Comment: what do you mean by adding, where are you adding, whats the function to add api key??

Comment: i dont know whats problem i have seen my package of mailchimp its fine and running this code exactly but nothing is happening its contunuously adding a random string

Comment: please figure out yourself, that is something to do with your logic not with checking mailchip api for sure because i have checked it before updating this question. try to debug your code line by line and try to understand what is happening, that may help you

Comment: i am adding this into the database after adding i want to get lists from this apikey .. thats why when i will get the lists based on api key this key should be valid.

Comment: and when i add i want to check it valid apikey if its not valid it should not allow me to enter into the database. thats my simple logic

Comment: I can't take this further, try to figure out yourself, thanks for your cooperation

Comment: Thanks for your coperation